# What options exist for logging off users after x time of inactivity?

Tags: network, nist, group-policy

I'm looking at [NIST SC-10](https://nvd.nist.gov/800-53/Rev4/control/sc-10), and I thought something simple would exist in Group Policy that would control this, but I haven't been able to find anything built in.

Things I've thought about trying:

- Deploy some kind of script that disables the user NIC after x time of inactivity.
- Deploy some kind of script that logs users off after x time of inactivity **(This is the most likely because there's another control that requires logoff after x amount of time)**

Are there other options, or some way that is considered more standard in controlling logoff and/or disabling networking after x amount of time of inactivity?

Comment: We used this: https://github.com/lithnet/idle-logoff

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that.  I'll post here how it goes.